# Randomness in the norm of sum of vectors

Tags: probability, vectors, normal-distribution, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be vectors and $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ be random iid scalars distributed by $N~(0,\sigma^2).$

Then, is it possible to lower bound the probability that $\lVert\sum a_i x_i\rVert \geq \lVert x_1 \rVert$?

Edit: We can represent $x_i$'s as columns of a matrix **X** and represent $a_i$'s as a vector $a$~$N(0,\sigma^2I)$. In that case, $\lVert\sum a_i x_i\rVert =\lVert Xa\rVert$. I have tried to find some lower bound as:$\lVert\sum a_i x_i\rVert =\lVert Xa\rVert \geq \lVert a \rVert \lVert x_1 \rVert$ and then find a lower bound of $Pr[ \lVert a \rVert \geq1]$, but couldn't succeed (actually tried to use the fact that $\lVert Xa\rVert \geq \sigma_{min}(X) \lVert a \rVert)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You can use MathJax to make your math formulas more readable to other users.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @quasicoherent_drunk

Comment: What does "show with a minimum probability" mean? Does it mean to show that there is a positive probability that the inequality holds?

Comment: Yes. It need to be shown that, the inequality holds with probability of at least 1/e.

Answer (score 1):

To find $P(\lVert\sum a_i x_i\rVert \geq \lVert x_1 \rVert)$ you must first find a CDF of $\lVert\sum a_i x_i\rVert$. If we denote it $f$, then the corresponding probability is $1-f(\lVert x_1 \rVert)$. But how to find $f$.

First, let's find the distribution of $\sum a_i x_i$. To do that, we represent the vectors as the columns of $d \times n$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix} x_{1,1} & ... & x_{1, n} \\ ... & ... & ... \\ x_{d, 1} & ... & x_{d, n} \end{pmatrix}$. Denote it's rows ar $y_1, ... y_d$. Then, $\sum a_i x_i \sim N\Big(0, \sigma^2\begin{pmatrix} (y_1, y_1) & ... & (y_1, y_d) \\ ... & ... & ... \\ (y_d, y_1) & ... & (y_d, y_d) \end{pmatrix}\Big)$.

So, we now have a normal vector with known mean and covariance matrix and want to find the distribution of this norm. The question how to do that is answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/155829/110691).

Comment: What does it mean by "($y_1$,$y_1$)"? Does it mean variance/covariance between them? For your information, $x_i$'s are fixed vectors, not random. Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Lemma_infinity, $(x, y)$ is the scalar product of fixed vectors $x$ and $y$. Nothing random here.